# Auto Create Statistics option is it for specific query ? confused

Tags: sql-server, database

Does the AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON switches this option for the entire database permanently or it applies only to the currently executed query? Have been reading on number of websites but this is not clearly stated.

Comment: It is a database-specific option and is persisted. You can view this in SSMS under the "database properties".

Comment: @user2864740 - Please add that as an answer to get this off the unanswered list.